# How long does a push notification sit in queue before being removed?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I've been digging around trying to uncover some data for apple's push notifications for a client and something I have been unable to find an answer to is how long a push notification will sit in queue for an offline device before it will be removed.

There maybe long periods of time, 2-3 months for example, in which the device maybe inactive and powered off. I'm simply interested in knowing how long I can expect a notification to linger, waiting to be delivered to an offline device, before it gets automatically removed (which is what I understand to be what happens).

Comment: To be safe, your server could expose an API endpoint to your app that allows your app to directly poll your server on launch for a set of notifications since a specific date.

Comment: If APNS servers storing the message for a long time is a problem, why don't you just send an 'empty' push notification to manually expire the message. The QoS on APNS will only queue one message.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Official developer documentation isn't clear about this. From [developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/APNSOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH8-SW1):

> Apple Push Notification Service includes a default Quality of Service
>   (QoS) component that performs a store-and-forward function. If APNs
>   attempts to deliver a notification but the device is offline, the QoS
>   stores the notification. It retains only one notification per
>   application on a device: the last notification received from a
>   provider for that application. When the offline device later
>   reconnects, the QoS forwards the stored notification to the device.
>   **The QoS retains a notification for a limited period before deleting
>   it.**

But according to [PCWorld](http://www.pcworld.com/article/167652/the_limits_of_apples_push_notification_for_the_iphone.html), it's 28 days:

> If the app is running, it gets the notification immediately. If the
>   app isn't running, the notification is held in the phone to be
>   consumed at the app's next launch. If the iPhone is offline when the
>   sender attempts delivery, APNS attempts to send the notification for
>   28 days.

While 28 days may have been true in 2009, I wouldn't be surprised if its different today. The ambiguity in the documentation is a great excuse for Apple to change this timeout period willy-nilly.

Comment: Thanks. I had read anywhere from 28-30 days, and yes I saw the official ambiguous documentation that basically said 'eventually'. Thanks for the confirmation!

Comment: To verify this you would need 28-30 turned-off iPhones with notifications queued for each. Then turn one on each day until you don't get the message. They really didn't make this easy for us..

Comment: So, if I sent a new notification to a device that already had one lined up... the new notification would queue and the one in the queue would be removed? Correct?

Answer (score 3):

Upon digging the docs I found out that we can use 'expiration date' parameter to control the queuing of APNS notifications.

[Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CommunicatingwithAPNs.html) is the detailed explanation on the usage of expiration date

> `apns-expiration`
>
> A UNIX epoch date expressed in seconds (UTC). This header identifies the date when the notification is no longer valid and can be discarded.
>
> If this value is nonzero, APNs stores the notification and tries to deliver it at least once, repeating the attempt as needed if it is unable to deliver the notification the first time. If the value is `0`, APNs treats the notification as if it expires immediately and does not store the notification or attempt to redeliver it.

Comment: where? your url is not active or invalid

Comment: Fixed the link.

Comment: Unfortunately this documentation does not guarantee anything about retention.  If I specify an expiration date 10 years in the future I highly doubt the service will retain it for that long.  Also, the documentation neglects to mention what happens if the expiration date is not specified.