# What is the number of persistent connections to APNS allowed?

Tags: iphone, ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am trying to write a server side code for sending push notifications for my applications.  As per Apple recommendation, I am planning to retain the connection and send push notification as required.
Apple also allows opening and retaining multiple parallel connections for sending push notifications.
"You may establish multiple, parallel connections to the same gateway or to multiple gateway instances."
For this purpose I would like to maintain a connections pool.
My question is what is the limitation of connections pool, or the number of persistent connections with APNS can I maintain?
Thanks for anticipated help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Don't know if you're going to get a precise answer to this one.** As large and dynamic a system as APNS is, it behooves Apple to be ambiguous about such a number; it gives them liberty to change it at will. I found a similar vagueness [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8608849/how-long-does-a-push-notification-sit-in-queue-before-being-removed/8609032#8609032).

- From [this discussion](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/57520-performance-push-notification-service.html) it appears a rule of thumb is **15 connections** max

One suggestion is to have an open-ended pool where new connections can be created until they start being refused.  Just an idea.

Comment: Thanks. I checked, the Javapns documentation also quotes the same rule of thumb.

Comment: @DonDyck Could you post that link? Thx

Comment: http://notnoop.github.com/java-apns/apidocs/com/notnoop/apns/ApnsServiceBuilder.html

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @paislee, I don't think you'll get a precise number. I'm opening over 20 distinct connections simultaneously and there are ok.

In order to help you with your test, use TcpView, where it is possible to see every opened connection.

Regards