# APNS notifications TTL

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I'm successfully using APNS to send notifications from a webapp to users who have the companion iOS app installed on their device.

Now, I'm looking for a way to specify a sort of TTL for the notifications so that users don't receive out-of-date information.

This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8608849/how-long-does-a-push-notification-sit-in-queue-before-being-removed) states that notifications (at least the last one for each user) are kept for about a month before being deleted, which is too long for me.

Is there a solution to either specify a TTL for a notification or to recall/delete a previously sent one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In [Communicating with APNs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CommunicatingwithAPNs.html) it states that you can set an Expiration date to notifications:

> A UNIX epoch date expressed in seconds (UTC). This header identifies the date when the notification is no longer valid and can be discarded. If this value is nonzero, APNs stores the notification and tries to deliver it at least once, repeating the attempt as needed if it is unable to deliver the notification the first time. If the value is 0, APNs treats the notification as if it expires immediately and does not store the notification or attempt to redeliver it.

Comment: The referenced URL has become invalid.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CommunicatingwithAPNs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH11-SW13 Updated url

Answer (score 1):

Don't think we can do that. You can probably send a timestamp with your notification payload and have the app check it once it does receive the notification. This way your app can let the user know if its outdated.

Comment: So I think I'll end up doing something like that... I was hoping to find another solution... Thanks!

Comment: According to this link and the answer below this is now possible with "apns-expiration" https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CommunicatingwithAPNs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH11-SW13