# Concurrent connections to Apple Push Notification Service

Tags: ios, iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

From rumour around it seems that there should not be more than lets' say 15 simultaneous connections to APNS. How are those connections counted? Is it per single server or per all servers? I guess all servers but I'd like to something more specific in doc somewhere. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

As large and dynamic a system as APNS is, it behooves Apple to be ambiguous about such a number; it gives them liberty to change it at will. I found a similar vagueness [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8608849/how-long-does-a-push-notification-sit-in-queue-before-being-removed/8609032#8609032)

From [this discussion](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/57520-performance-push-notification-service.html) it appears a **rule of thumb is 15 connections max**

One suggestion is to have an open-ended pool where new connections can be created until they start being refused