# How long are notifications stored on APNS servers?

Tags: ios, iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

In the Quality of Service section in the [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html), it states:

> If APNs attempts to deliver a notification but the device is offline,
>   the notification is stored for a limited period of time, and delivered
>   to the device when it becomes available.

Does anyone know how long "a limited period of time" is, and whether they are then deleted from APNS once they are sent?

Comment: Normally something like that means there isn't a set amount of time and it could change. It might be 24 hours one day and then 6 hours the next.

Answer (score 2):

Same question asked here :
[How long does a push notification sit in queue before being removed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8608849/how-long-does-a-push-notification-sit-in-queue-before-being-removed)

According to [PCWorld](http://www.techhive.com/article/167652/the_limits_of_apples_push_notification_for_the_iphone.html) (in 2009), it's 28 days.

> While 28 days may have been true in 2009, I wouldn't be surprised if its >different today. The ambiguity in the documentation is a great excuse for >Apple to change this timeout period willy-nilly.

Comment: If you find the same question here on stackoverflow, flag the new question as a duplicat instead of adding an answer with a link to the already existing question...